# Unable to catch a String field that is passed as ""

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a search Field that when it does not have a value it will be passed as "".  as mentioned in Visual Studio exception details.
So i am trying to handle this value but none of these succeed:-

```
if (UserName != null || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) || UserName != "" ){
 UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, UserName);
if (user == null) {
 yield return new ValidationResult("UserName does not exsists."); }
```

But even if the field left empty the code will reach the

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, UserName);
```

and an exception will be raised .

Comment: use && operartor insted of ||

Comment: If userName is `""` then `UserName != null` would be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName)` rest are redundant. `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` also test for white space.

Answer (score 6):

`string.IsNullOrEmpty( UserName )`

Will cover most of what you're already doing in that test expression.

The only other thing I can see is the IsNullOrWhiteSpace check, but all the extra `!= ""` are entirely redundant.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use && operator as in your if statment if one of the expression will return true the whole exresssion will be true

Answer (score 0):

```
if (UserName != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName) &&!String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) && UserName != "" ){
 UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, UserName);
if (user == null) {
 yield return new ValidationResult("UserName does not exsists."); }
```